# Kafka: All messages failing in stream while data in topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have topic `post_users_t`and while use `PRINT` command on it I get

```
rowtime: 4/2/20 2:03:48 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"userid": 6, "id": 8, "title": "testest", "body": "Testingmoreand more"}
rowtime: 4/2/20 2:03:48 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"userid": 7, "id": 11, "title": "testest", "body": "Testingmoreand more"}
```

So then I create a stream out of this with:

```
CREATE STREAM userstream (userid INT, id INT, title VARCHAR, body VARCHAR)
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='post_users_t',
          VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

But I cant select anything from it and when I `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` it all the messages have failed.

```
consumer-messages-per-sec:      1.06 consumer-total-bytes:    116643 consumer-total-messages:      3417     last-message: 2020-04-02T14:08:08.546Z
consumer-failed-messages:      3417 consumer-failed-messages-per-sec:      1.06      last-failed: 2020-04-02T14:08:08.56Z
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Extra info under!

Print topic from beginning:

```
ksql> print 'post_users_t' from beginning limit 2;
Key format: SESSION(AVRO) or HOPPING(AVRO) or TUMBLING(AVRO) or AVRO or SESSION(PROTOBUF) or HOPPING(PROTOBUF) or TUMBLING(PROTOBUF) or PROTOBUF or SESSION(JSON) or HOPPING(JSON) or TUMBLING(JSON) or JSON or SESSION(JSON_SR) or HOPPING(JSON_SR) or TUMBLING(JSON_SR) or JSON_SR or SESSION(KAFKA_INT) or HOPPING(KAFKA_INT) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_INT) or KAFKA_INT or SESSION(KAFKA_BIGINT) or HOPPING(KAFKA_BIGINT) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_BIGINT) or KAFKA_BIGINT or SESSION(KAFKA_DOUBLE) or HOPPING(KAFKA_DOUBLE) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_DOUBLE) or KAFKA_DOUBLE or SESSION(KAFKA_STRING) or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 4/2/20 1:04:08 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"userid": 1, "id": 1, "title": "loremit", "body": "loremit heiluu ja paukkuu"}
rowtime: 4/2/20 1:04:08 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"userid": 2, "id": 2, "title": "lorbe", "body": "larboloilllaaa"}
```

Comment: can you post the full output of `PRINT post_users_t FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 2` please

Comment: also what version of Confluent Platform are you running?

Comment: Hey @RobinMoffatt . Thank you once again for quick answer. I added the print from the beginning and actually i havent used limit on it before so i havent seen this output before.

Comment: Oh yeah and im running everything on docker and you can find the docker-compose here: https://github.com/Itzblend/KafkaPOC/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the output from ksqlDB's inspection of the topic, your data is serialised in Avro:

```
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
```

but you have created the `STREAM` specifying `VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'`. This will result in deserialisation errors which if you run `docker-compose logs -f ksqldb-server` you'll see being written out when you try to query the stream.

Since you're using Avro, you don't need to specify the schema. Try this instead:

```
CREATE STREAM userstream 
   WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='post_users_t',
         VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

Comment: Amazing! Got it to work exactly with your advice. I wonder what specified it to do it as AVRO. Thanks again for the quick answer and I want to say i love your talks. They are one of the best in all tech field!